# EF 6 Code First, How to persist delete operation in a referenced ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm struggling with deleting entities in memory, which are not pushed to the database.

A Blog entity references 0..n entries in a Posts collection.

Adding or changing Posts entries wil generate Update or Insert statements after SaveChanges on the Context object.

But when i delete a Post, then this delete operation is not pushed to the database.

To repro my problem, I created this small sample using the Blog / Posts model shown below.

My scenario is a web based app, where a blog entry and all related posts should be loaded on the first request and then the posts collection should be modified and should be saved to the DB on another request.

I try to simulate this scenario with the 2 different DbContext instances readCtx & writeCtx in the sample code below.

Adding or changing Post entries works fine, I get Update statements for every Post entry.

BUT: My way of deleting a single post does not get pushed to the database and I'm not sure, how EF is intended to be used for this.

If I remove the posts entry as shown below, then EF does ignore it and does not issue a delete statement.

The posts collection should be bound to the UI, so I would like to reflect any changes inside into the database.

What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFDeleteTest
{


    public class Blog
    {
        public Blog()
        {
            Posts = new List<Post>();
        }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogSystemDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public BlogSystemDbContext() {     }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void LogSql(string sqlStmt)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sqlStmt);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Blog blog = null; // Should be used in the web app for binding it to the UI

            using (var readCtx = new BlogSystemDbContext())
            {
                blog = readCtx.Blogs.Include(b1 => b1.Posts).Where(b2 => b2.Name == "Blog X").SingleOrDefault();
            }

            // Simulate the next HTTP Request
            using (var writeCtx = new BlogSystemDbContext())
            {
                writeCtx.Database.Log = LogSql;
                // delete the last post:
                int count = blog.Posts.Count;
                var postToDelete = blog.Posts.Skip(count - 1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
                blog.Posts.Remove((Post)postToDelete);

                writeCtx.Blogs.Attach(blog);
                writeCtx.Entry(blog).State = blog.BlogId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;


                foreach (var post in blog.Posts)
                {
                    writeCtx.Entry(post).State = post.PostId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                }
                writeCtx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BlogSystemDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BlogSystemDB;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true " />
    </connectionStrings>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by...

```
writeCtx.Blogs.Attach(blog);
writeCtx.Entry(blog).State = blog.BlogId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
```

You only mark `blog` as modified, not its `Posts` collection. The collection isn't even tracked at all by EF. This is a design fact.

There are several ways to solve this. An expensive solution is to re-fetch the `blog`, including its `Posts`, from the database and remove the post from the collection that is now change-tracked.

A cheaper solution is to create a *stub entity*...

```
var post = new Post { ID = blog.Posts.Skip(count - 1).Take(1).ID };
```

...and attach it to the context as `Deleted`.

I can't judge which option would work for you in the real application, but of course you should try the cheap option.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks for your response, which actually helped me to understand how EF is working.
I know now, that all change tracking is done on context level and that i have to attach an object, if i want the change tracking mechanism to help me.

Thanks